# Variable not defined when i've defined it?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that creates passwords. The problem is that when the function "lettersymbolorNumber" tries to execute, it says the variables "symbol", "letter", and "number" are not defined even though I've already defined them.

```
import random
passwordString = ""
passwordList = []
passwordLength = int(input("How many characters do you want the password to have? "))
def numberGenerator():
    number = random.randint(0, 9)
    return number
def symbolGenerator():
    symbolNumber = random.randint(33, 47)
    symbol = chr(symbolNumber)
    return symbol
def letterGenerator():
    uppercaseLowercase = random.randint(1,2)
    if (uppercaseLowercase == 2):
        letterNumber = random.randint(65, 90)
    if (uppercaseLowercase == 1):
        letterNumber = random.randint(97, 122)
    letter = chr(letterNumber)
    return letter

def lettersymbolorNumber():
    lettersNumbers = random.randint(1,3)
    if (lettersNumbers == 1):
        passwordList.append(number)
    if (lettersNumbers == 2):
        passwordList.append(letter)
    if (lettersNumbers == 3):
        passwordList.append(symbol)
while (passwordLength > 0):
    letterGenerator()
    numberGenerator()
    symbolGenerator()
    lettersymbolorNumber()
    passwordLength = passwordLength - 1

for i in passwordList:
    passwordString += str(i)
print("The password that has generated is", passwordString)
```

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `symbol`, `letter` and `number` are defined in the local scope of the functions `numberGenerator`, `symbolGenerator`, etc, which means that outside those functions they don't exist. Consider reading about `scope` and passing arguments between functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined functions that returns `letter`, `symbol` and `number`. But you haven't called these functions and set its return value to some variable.

I.e. you could do `letter = letterGenerator()`